# Is it reliable to check stripe subscription status in frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, security, frontend, stripe-payments

I'm having the Stripe subscription form right after the user sign up into the app. But it is always displaying the subscription form whenever the user opens the app even though the user has already subscribed.

What if I get the subscription object from the backend and validate the subscription status. And display the components based on the status. Is it reliable? are there any possibilities of savvy user bypassing this?

Answer (score 1):

As a rule you should never provision access to your app or service from the frontend. It would be trivial to trick your frontend into giving access despite not paying if all it needs is a response from your backend.

In your case you should have an authentication system so you can reliably determine if the logged in user has paid up or not.

Comment: Yes. I'm having an authentication system.

Comment: How to provide access to service from backend? any idea?